# Fit To Window in WPF Mvvm

Tags: wpf

am new to WPF MVVM, i had an issue with fit to window  with zoom in and zoom out
for zoom in and zoom out it is working fine, but on clicking on fit to window content is not setting to actual window height and width. instead there is scrollbar which should not be displayed on fit to window content should be fit to window layout .. is there anything which can help me out.

```
<!-- Layout display area -->
<dxlc:LayoutItem Focusable="False"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid"
         Margin="1">
      <dx:ThemedBorder BorderThickness="1"
                       Margin="5,0,1,2">
         <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                       VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DrawingSurface}"  
                              Height="{Binding CanvasHeight}"
                              Width="{Binding CanvasWidth}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top">
               <ContentPresenter.ContextMenu>
                  <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding WorkingCanvas.ContextMenuItems}" />
               </ContentPresenter.ContextMenu>
            </ContentPresenter>
            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
               <b:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
                  <b:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnSizeChanged"
                                      TargetObject="{Binding}" />
               </b:EventTrigger>
            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
         </ScrollViewer>
      </dx:ThemedBorder>
   </Grid>
</dxlc:LayoutItem>
```

Comment: hide the scrollbars

Comment: or you maybe setting SnapsToDevicePixels to true works

Comment: hiding is not a good option , because it is simultaneously required during the time of zoom in and zoom out. sot at initial load it should be fit to window  and then with scroll bar it should have zoom in and zoom out

Comment: what about 0.1 pixels less margin? or if it looks blurry 1 less margin. to always fit everything regardless of rounding.